# Aligning equations at more than 3 positions using alignat

Tags: amsmath, alignat

I am trying to align two equations with `alignat` at 4-5 points but I can't get it to work, even though having read several similar questions and the amsmath documentation. Using 3, 4 or 5 as argument for `alignat` doesn't matter.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{alignat}{5}
    R(N,||E||^2) &= &R_{SRH} + &R_{spont} + &R_{Auger} + &R_{stim} \nonumber\\
                 &= &AN + &BN^2 + &CN^3 + &R_{stim}(N,||E||^2)
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

What I get looks like this:
[image: output aligning terms]

I have also tried aligning the plus signs which looks like this:
[image: output aligning plus signs]

What am I doing wrong? Thanks for your help!

Greetings

Comment: Remember the number of `&`'s, it is 2 x (number of alignments) - 1, one `&` for each alignment and (number of alignmens minus 1) `&` to separate the alignment columns. So in short you need more `&`'s. Remember that each alignment has two parts, a left hand side and a right hand side. The left hand is right aligned, the right hand is left aligned. In your case you will probably have a lot of empty left hand sides, so a lot of `&&`'s

Comment: Also `||E||` is not how one makes a norm. Use `amssymb` and `\lVert` and `\rVert` or additionally use `mathtools` and buid a norm macro using `\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image]

Considering @daleif  comments below your question, the MWE is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{4}
R(N,\norm{E}^2) &= R_{SRH} &+& R_{spont}   && + R_{Auger} && + R_{stim} \notag\\
                &= AN      &+& BN^2        && + CN^3      && + R_{stim}(N,\norm{E}^2)
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**
More correct and consistent is placement of ampersand as suggested @Bernard in his comment:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{scrbook}
\usepackage{amssymb, mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\norm\lVert\rVert

\begin{document}
    \begin{alignat}{5}
R(N,\norm{E}^2) 
    &= R_\mathit{SRH} && + R_\mathit{spont} && + R_\mathit{Auger} && + R_\mathit{stim} \notag\\
    &= AN             && + BN^2             && + CN^3             && + R_\mathit{stim}(N,\norm{E}^2)
    \end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

which gives:

[image]

With this ampersands arrangement is simpler to imagine function of them. Odd ampersand serve as alignment anchors (everything left of them are right aligned, and opposite everything right of them are left aligned. Even ampersands serve as delimiter of columns of aligned pairs.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Now, would you please explain why and how your variant works?

Comment: @Christian, my example works since I consider the first @daleif's  comments :-). Shortly, at the first `&` are aligned first term at right side and sign `=` at left side, the second align the next pair of terms, at which signs `+` are aligned at right side and next term at their left side etc. After `&&` term is aligned to their left side and the same is on the end. At `&&` the first ampersand determine the next pair of terms, where the first one (which is aligned at right side) is empty.

Comment: Yeah, I read daleif's comments but couldn't figure out the solution. In fact, I still don't fully grasp every aspect of the alignment logic. Guess, I need to practice some more. ;) You also added spaces which are essential, too, am I right?

Comment: @Christian, I always try to write equations, arrays, tables etc in editor on a way that I can easily find for example ampersands or that structure remains me on result of compilation of my code. This help me in searching for errors in code. You will obtain the same result if you omit all empty spaces in my MWE (Minimal Working Example).

Comment: @Zarko: I think the spacing would be better with `&&+` also in he second column

Comment: @Bernard, you are right. With this the system of ampersands placement is more consistent. Also spaces around sign`+` is improved. I will add this aasap.

Comment: Awesome, this looks even better. Thanks to both of you, also for letting me know about mathint! Since we (you) are already fine-tuning, I'd like to know whether there is a possibility to center every term of the 2nd equation in respect to the terms in the 1st equation? Spaces don't seem to matter after all.

Comment: (sry, couldn't edit anymore) Also, why do you use 5 as argument? You use 3 pairs of `&&` to separate 4 columns, right? Then, there are the single `&` serving as left-handed alignment anchor to everything right of it.

Comment: @Christian I count 4 alignment groups in @Zark'os example. 2*4-1 `&`'s, the first `&` is an alignment, the second is a separator, third is an alignment with an empty left hand side, and so forth. I The correct number of alignment coulmns would be 4, but 5 does not hurt. It would have been nice to have two chars with the same catcode as `&`, then one could be used to mark alignment and the other to mark separation between alignment columns and thius syntax would have been much more clear.

Comment: @Christian here us a mental image to have. We are here looking at a table/array with no spacing between the columns. The columns of the structure are arranged in groups of two collectively named "an alignment column" (even if it is two columns). In an alignment col we have a left and a right column, one is right aligned the other is left aligned. If you have this mental image to see this as a tabular construction of pairs of columns you'll hopefully notice that we are missing some `&`, those between the alignment columns (pairs)

Comment: @daleif: Thank you very much! This does help, indeed. :)